# Kafka publish not consuming in @KafkaListener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have provided 2 consumerFactory

1. handling normal topics
2. handling retrying topics

Also 2 @KafkaListener methods for above cases

I'm trying to publish the failed/exception occurred events to a new topic "event-retry" so that other events will not need to wait until the failed one is resolved, The publish is working(no errors) but its not being consumed instantly in @KafkaListener method, but that events do get consumed when restarting server.

Kafka config

```java
     // @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<String, Message> consumerFactoryMain() {
            Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, kafkaMaxPollRecords);
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
                    new ErrorHandlingDeserializer2(new JsonDeserializer(Message.class)));
    
        }
    
        @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactoryMain")
        public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryMain() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryMain());
            factory.setConcurrency(kafkaListenerConcurrency);
            return factory;
        }
    
        // @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<String, Message> consumerFactoryRetry() {
            Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, kafkaMaxPollRecords);
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
                    new ErrorHandlingDeserializer2(new JsonDeserializer(Message.class)));
        }
    
        @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactoryRetry")
        public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryRetry() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryRetry());
            factory.setConcurrency(kafkaListenerConcurrency);
            return factory;
        }
```

Kafka Consumer

```java
    @KafkaListener(topics = { "order-updated", "order-created", "order-rejected", "order-shipped", "order-cancelled",
                "order-delivered", "order-packed", "order-accepted", "update", "created", "reject", "shipped",
                "cancel" }, groupId = "group_id",containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryMain")
        public void consumeOmsEvents(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                @Payload(required = false) Message message) {
            System.out.println("Got NEW Event for topic from kafka: " + topic);
            System.out.println("Received: " + topic + " to: " + message.getTargetUrl());
            try {
                subscriberService.sendWebhook(message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (message.getRetryCount() < retryCount) {
                    kafkaTemplate.send("event-retry", message);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Success: " + message.getTargetUrl());
        }
    
        @KafkaListener(topics = { "event-retry" }, groupId = "group_id",containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryRetry")
        public void consumeRetryOmsEvents(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                @Payload(required = false) Message message) {
            System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Got Retry Event for topic from kafka: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + topic);
            System.out.println("Received Retry: " + topic + " to: " + message.getTargetUrl() + " count ="+message.getRetryCount());
            try {
                if (message.getRetryCount() < retryCount) {
                    subscriberService.sendWebhook(message);
                } else {
                    subscriberService.disableSubscriber(message);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (message.getRetryCount() < retryCount) {
                    message.setRetryCount(message.getRetryCount() + 1);
                    kafkaTemplate.send("event-retry", message);
                }
    
            }
        }
```

Comment: You've not set `auto.offset.reset`, so the consumer would start at the very end of the topic.

Comment: Debug logging should help you figure out what is wrong.